GCP : Unable to delete my Composer Environnement
I'm trying to upgrade my cloud composer environnement on gcp from the version 2.4.1 to the version 2.8.1.
I created a new environnement with the new version and now I'm trying to delete the old one.
Using Terraform I deleted my resources but I have this error :
DELETE operation on this environment failed 5 hours ago with the following error message:
DELETE operation failed. Polled operation status: DONE: Google Compute Engine: The subnetwork resource 'projects/my-project/regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/subnet-vpc' is already being used by 'projects/my-project/zones/europe-west1-b/instances/gk3-europe-west1-composer-241--pool-2-543ac353-w6l2'.
I tried to delete the GKE clusters but I get the same error
I also tried to delete the instances using the google cli but it said that the instances does not exist.
Any ideas what can I do ?

Unfamiliar with Cloud Composer and your question is likely to be closed as it's not programming related but, my hunch is that your new Compose environment is reusing the subnet which is why it cannot be deleted. If that's true, you can safely ignore the error.

As per the error message, it seems that the node of the new composer I.e. "gk3-europe-west1-composer-241--pool-2-543ac353-w6l2" in the region "europe-west1-b" is using the same subnet. Therefore, it's required to delete the resources which are using the network before deleting the old one.
